# You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack

Вылетает ошибка в `webpack` при попытке срендерить этот код:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';


class Hello extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (<h1>Hello</h1>)
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Hello/>, document.getElementById('hello'));
```

Лог в консоли:

```
ERROR in ./web_client/app.js
Module parse failed: D:\doSociety\Product\Site\web_client\app.js Unexpected token (8:12)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| class Hello extends React.Component {
|   render() {
|     return (<h1>Hello</h1>)
|   }
| }
```

Содержимое `webpack.config.js`:

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');


module.exports = {
   entry:  './web_client/app.js',
   output:  {
       path: './society/static/js/',
       filename: 'app.js'
   },
   resolve: {
       extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx', '.scss'],
       modulesDirectories: [
           'node_modules'
       ]
   },
   module: {
       rules: [
           {
               test: /\.jsx?$/,
               use: [
                  {loaders: 'babel-loader'}
               ],
               include: [
                    "web_client"
               ],
              exclude: /node_modules/,
               query: {
                   plugins: ['transform-runtime'],
                   presets: ['es2015', 'stage-0', 'react']
               }
           },
           {
               test: /\.s[a|c]ss$/,
               use: [
                'style-loader',
                'css-loader',
                'sass-loader'
               ]
           }
       ]
   },
   sassLoader: {
       includePaths: [
          "./web_client",
           "./node_modules/bootstrap/scss"
       ]
   }
}
```

`Webpack` версии `2.2.0`
Поправил конфиг на:

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');


module.exports = {
   entry:  './web_client/app.js',
   output:  {
       path: './society/static/js/',
       filename: 'app.js'
   },
   resolve: {
       extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx', '.scss'],
       modulesDirectories: [
           'node_modules'
       ]
   },
   module: {
    loaders: [{
      test: /\.js$/,
      loaders: ['babel'],
    }]
   }
}
```

Начало выдавать:

```
Module build failed: SyntaxError: D:/doSociety/Product/Site/web_client/app.js: Unexpected token (8:12)

   6 | class Hello extends React.Component {
   7 |   render() {
>  8 |     return (<h1>Hello</h1>)
     |             ^
   9 |   }
  10 | }
  11 |
```

Comment: Попробуйте обновить бабель лоадер, там был похожий баг при переходе на второй вебпак. Посмотрите эти ишью:
https://github.com/babel/babel-loader/issues/380  и вот эту
https://github.com/babel/babel-loader/issues/381

Comment: Соответственно беглый взгляд по этим ишью показывает что это связано либо со структурой проекта где есть еще одна папочка node_modules которая игнорится (логично) или с багом в конкретной версии лоадера вероятно связанным с кешированием (очистить ручками кеш лоадера?)

Comment: поправил webpack.config.js 
теперь выдает: Module build failed: SyntaxError: D:/doSociety/Product/Site/web_client/app.js: Unexpected token (8:12)

Comment: дополнил вопрос

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Надо в конфиге `babel` включить пресет `react`:

Файл `.babelrc` содержимое

```
{
  "presets": ["react"]
}
```

https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-react/

На самом деле, может понадобиться подключить ещё несколько пресетов, если поддержка браузерами ES6 не соответствует желаемой.

Comment: только что хотел ответить на свой вопрос.Да, именно так я и решил свою проблему